# My ffmpeg commands result in very compressed video when blending with music. TYIA

Tags: flutter, ffmpeg, mobile-ffmpeg

I have a flutter app that combines music with video. Below is the command I am using, but the resulting video has a very blurry/compressed look. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

-i $pathOfVideo -i $_localMusic -y -map 0:v -map 1:a -shortest $f${Platform.pathSeparator}out.mp4

I have tried adding   "-crf 20 -preset veryfast"    but it did not work

Comment: Anyone have an idea? TYIA